# Creating a JavaScript Object from Single Array and Defining the Key Value Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

this my post in stack over flow

I have a problem to convert single Array to Array of Object

This is a portion of my javascript code

```
var str = 'this is the haystack {{{name}}} {{{address}}} some text {{{grade}}} end of haystack';
var result = getFromBetween.get(str,"{{{","}}}");
var resultObject = Object.assign({}, result)
```

the resultObject is

```
{0: "name", 1: "address", 2: "grade"}
```

I want resultObject like this

```
[
{position : "0", value:"name"},
{position : "1", value:"address"},
{position : "2", value:"grade"}
]
```

How to do it in javascript, help me because I'm really a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` over `Object.entries`:

```
var resultObject = Object.assign({}, result)
resultObject = Object.entries(resultObject).map(([position,value])=>({position,value}));
```